# How to modify label in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a UITableView with static cells.  How can I modify the label that is added in the cell to give it an offset of 50 points from the edge so that the icon appears next to it?

[image]

All the usual constraint options are greyed out, as are the Frame Rectangle items in the View section (ie, the x and y coordinates)

Comment: Have you tried updating the frame for the Label ?

Comment: Yes, not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the cell type to custom and add your own subviews. You can't modify the layout of the default views (the label, detail label, and image view) in a table view cell.

Having said that, if you use the official image view of the cell, it should just work.